# Building util-linux: unsupported hardcode properties

Tags: linux, libtool

I'm trying to build util-linux on ubuntu 12.04.

But make stops with this error:

```
libtool: link: unsupported hardcode properties
libtool: link: See the libtool documentation for more information.
libtool: link: Fatal configuration error.
make[2]: *** [libblkid.la] Error 1
```

After googling this error, it seems to me this kind of error is linked with "cross compilation". Although i'm building it in native environment.

The error occurs during linking `libblkid`

I then tried building it with `./configure --disable-libblkid`, then it stops with the same error. This time it chokes when building `libfdisk`. And it turns out i can't disable building `libfdisk`.

So i'm very curious about what this error actually means?

EDIT:

During `./autogen.sh` this error comes up. Although it does not stop the process.

```
configure.ac:129: error: Could not locate the pkg-config autoconf
    macros. These are usually located in /usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4.
    If your macros are in a different location, try setting the
    environment variable AL_OPTS="-I/other/macro/dir" before running
    ./autogen.sh or autoreconf again.
```

Comment: cannot reproduce. (using default `./configure`) I'm using ubuntu 12.04 AMD 64

Comment: Me too, I'm using util-linux git repo. Maybe this does not occur in release tarballs.

Comment: will have a try with the git version later and give you feedback. do you have the clone url (I'm lazy :)?

Comment: `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git util-linux`

Comment: You can try the github mirror : `https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux.git`

Comment: Have compiled the git version. Again, cannot reproduce.

Comment: (having executed autogen.sh as well, (as it is necessary)).